# Is it posible to UPDATE/PATCH certain file from StaticResource bundle using Tooling API?

Tags: metadata-api, static-resources, tooling-api

I have the **StaticResource** with name *AwesomeApplication* where placed zipped files (`bundle.js`, `vendor.bundle.js`).

Can I update only `bundle.js` from my **StaticResource**, without touching `vendor.bundle.js` using any Tooling API approach?

I'm working with [IlluminatedCloud](http://www.illuminatedcloud.com/) plugin and there are StaticResource files updating separately through Tooling API. I want to use this approach in my [webpack-sfdc-deploy-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-sfdc-deploy-plugin), to deploy only changed files, not all application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `StaticResource` is treated as a binary blob so you can't update any bytes within it. The approach we took on [Gearset](https://gearset.com) to allow this sort of functionality was to download the zip, extract it and then do the merge. It works well as an approach